# Projective tensor product continuous?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products, banach-algebras, banach-manifold

For $V$, $W$ Banach spaces, is the canonical morphism $B(V) \times_\pi B(W) \to B(V \hat{\otimes}_\pi W)$ continuous, where $B(V)$ denotes the set of all linear bounded endomorphisms with operator norm? If so, is it also smooth (wrt differential calculus in locally convex spaces, [see here](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/Math-Net/Lehrveranstaltungen/Lehrmaterial/SS2005/Liegruppen/skript/ch2vorl.pdf))? Does it induce a continuous (smooth) map $GL(V)\times_\pi GL(W) \to GL(V \hat{\otimes}_\pi W)$, where $GL(V)=B(V)^{\times}$.

**EDIT**: The answer of the very first question is yes

Comment: Assuming that $B$ means unit ball, that $\times_\pi$ means the Cartesian product, and you are equipping $B(V)\times B(W)$ with the product topology, then I think the answer to your first question should be yes by direct checking, using the definition of the projective tensor norm

Comment: As fpr your second question, what do you mean by "smooth"? What is your notion of differentiable mapping here?

Comment: No, sorry, $B$ denotes the internal Hom functor, i.e. bounded operators with operator norm and $B(V):=B(V,V)$. and yes, $\times_\pi$ is the cartesian product with product topology. moreover, I refer to smoothness wrt differential calculus in locally convex spaces, I put a link with an introduction by Helge Glöckner in..

Comment: The *canonical morphism* $(S,T)\mapsto S \otimes T$ is bilinear and continuous. Doesn't this imply smoothness? If so, then the restriction is also smooth.